# Storing my Logs to REDIS

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm a little confused.
I want to filter my records based on SL and HOST.
And I want to get records in date range.
I guess I couldn't understand the use of SADD and ZADD.

My code likes this :

```
console.log("sl:"+req.params.sl+" | host:"+req.params.host+" | source:"+req.params.source+" | date:"+req.body.date+" | title:"+req.body.title+" | details:"+req.body.details);
var key="log"+req.body.date;
redis_client.hmset(key,{"date":req.body.date,"title":req.body.title,"details":req.body.details,"sl":req.params.sl,"source":req.params.source,"host":req.params.host});
redis_client.sadd(key,"host",req.params.host,redis.print);
redis_client.sadd(key,"sl",req.params.host,redis.print);
redis_client.zadd(key,"date",req.body.date,redis.print);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a key can only get one type, here you define key as hash, set and zset

try construct the key name using your filter data

as you need get records in date range, using a single *list* key by day and host could be pertinent

```
var entry = {
    date:req.body.date,
    title:req.body.title,
    details:req.body.details,
    sl:req.params.sl,
    source:req.params.source,
    host:req.params.host
}

var key = 'mylog:'+req.params.host+':'+currentDay;

redis_client.rpush(key,entry);
redis_client.expire(key,30*24*60*60); // expire in one month
```

for catch all entry of a particular day for any host just use *lrange* command

```
function getLog(host,day,callback){
    redis_client.lrange('mylog:'+host+':'+day,0,-1,callback);
}
```

and you can use *keys* command to filter keys using wildcards (not do that in production *keys* is slow!)

```
function getLogDay(day,callback){
    redis_client.keys('mylog:*:'+day,function(keys){
        var multi = redis_client.multi(); // check your redis client real syntax
        // loop on result keys to get them all
        for(var n=0;n<keys.length;n++)
            multi.lrange(keys[n],0,-1);
        multi.exec(callback);
    });
}
```